# find words by one row only SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

how can I find rows which contain one or multi word on the same row
for example:

the result of the search to ( Monkey , horse) in the this table
[image]

using SQL or SQLite
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here this will be nice and slow:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE lower(animals) like '%horse%' and lower(animals) like '%monkey%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Full text search will be a good option in such scenarios.
And the feature is available from SQL 2005 + versions.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE CONTAINS(animals , '"Horse" AND "Monkey"');
```